# Voice Access taking forever to download language update

Tags: downloading, languages, accessibility, offline

I am running Android 12 on a Realme 8 5G phone. I am new to Voice Access. I have been following the tutorial to try and set it up, so that I can operate my phone and the user interface that it and its various apps provide entirely via voice. I am trying to download the US English language package from Italy. However, a language update was necessary to use it offline, and, as a result, the Voice Access tutorial stalls, as it takes forever.

Here is a screenshot:

> [image]

Comment: bump. I also have this issue with a device purchased in Britain. It still tries to download the US English language package and has the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, then I realised was not updating because wanted to be connected to external Wi-Fi instead of using my mobile data for some reason. Try to connect to a Wi-Fi and see if that works.

Comment: Tried this yesterday and it did not work. There doesn't seem to be any dedicated support for this issue either.